# Error while importing gensim package in colab

Tags: python, importerror, gensim

ImportError: cannot import name 'mean_absolute_difference'

Tried uninstalling and installing again.

```
import gensim
```

---

```
ImportError                          Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-28-e70e92d32c6e> in <module>()
----> 1 import gensim
2 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/gensim/models/hdpmodel.py in 
<module>()
 61 
 62 from gensim import interfaces, utils, matutils
 ---> 63 from gensim.matutils import dirichlet_expectation, 
 mean_absolute_difference
 64 from gensim.models import basemodel, ldamodel
 65 

 ImportError: cannot import name 'mean_absolute_difference'
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried installing `gensim` on my linux using `!pip install gensim` and after that i imported as you did it worked fine. Like shown below.

```
>>> !pip install gensim
>>> import gensim
>>> from gensim import interfaces, utils, matutils
>>> from gensim.matutils import dirichlet_expectation, mean_absolute_difference
>>>
```

Comment: Try doing it in Google colab.

Comment: add `!pip install gensim` to the top of the notebook.

Comment: Can you send the screenshot?

Comment: I opened a new notebook, and tried importing again, its working! Thanks for the help!